# Implementation of Google Analytics pageView event on a single page application behave weird

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, single-page-application

I provide SEO services to a customer of mine.

The customer website uses AngularJS as a single-page-application using ui-router to swipe between pages (views).

I having troubles with sending pageView event for each different page, I've asked him to follow the instructions in this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications).

He tried both:

```
 ga('set', {
  page: '/new-page',
  title: 'New Page'
});
```

and:

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page');
```

for each route (page) on the site.
When I check Google Analytics 'real time' dashboard I can see the pageView(s)
but it count as the home page in the reports data.

I've tried implement it as GTM as well and still nothing.

p.s the routes look a bit different then regular ui-router routes, it looks like that:

http://www.example.com/s#!/page_name

Any idea why and what should I do to fix it?

appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## First - reconfigure tracker

This code seems to be OK, if you use default tracker and namespace names. After sending first pageview, you reconfigure tracker values. Your solution is right, because it keeps values for e.g. events fired later on virtual page.

```
ga('set', {
  page: '/new-page',
  title: 'New Page'
});
```

## Second - send pageview again

After reconfiguring tracker, you have to send pageview again. 
You do not show a lot of your code, but I am missing sending pageview. I expect you need to use some Angular router's method.

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

## GTM alternations

The same is for GTM. Here you need firing event on virtual pageview and some data passed into dataLayer to update trackers values by **page** and **title** parameters. You have to recofigure **Custom fields** in PageView Tag settings.

## Better debugging

If you have this kind of probles, please, add HTTP log (or console log from analytics_debug.js or whatever where is full signal).

Live HTTP headers, Omnibug, Charles Web debugging proxy or any other similar analyzer will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Jakub, I checked again and I can see the implementation is wrong, it uses ONLY `ga('send', 'pageview', 'page-name');` I've asked the customer to change it to `ga('set','page','page-name'); ga('send','pageView');`